# Multiple data cursor with data tooltips on same x-axis with matplotlib or plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, visualization, data-analysis

I am trying to plot and analyze the data using matplotlib library as well as plotly.
The requirement is as below image (image is from a different app):
[image]

Details of the plot shown in the image is as follows:

1. X axis is time
2. Multiple Y axis for each data (temperature)
3. There are 2 cursors - Cursor A and Cursor B
4. Tooltips for each signal can be seen at Cursor A and Cursor B
5. Time Difference between Cursor A and Cursor B can also be seen
6. Both X-axis and Y-axis is interactive

I am checking multiple libraries (matplotlib, plotly & seaborn) in python but unable to find a library which can render the plot/graph similar to the image above.

Expectation:

1. Plot the data from .csv, .mf4, .dat etc... similar to the above image
2. Have multiple y axis that is interactive
3. Have 2 cursor
4. Tooltips for each signal at the place of cursor

I have tried using following lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor


x1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
y1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

x2 = np.random.rand(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)

x3 = np.random.randn(10)
y3 = np.random.randn(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, sharex = "col")

twin1 = ax.twinx()
twin1.spines["left"].set_position(("axes", 1))

p1, = ax.plot(x1, y1, "C0", label = "x1y1")
ax.set_xlabel("x1")
ax.set_ylabel("y1")

p2, = ax.plot(x2, y2, "C1", label = "x2y2")
ax.set_xlabel("x2")
ax.set_ylabel("y2")

p3, = twin1.plot(x3, y3, "C3", label = "x3y3")
twin1.set_xlabel("x3")
twin1.set_ylabel("y3")

cursor = MultiCursor(fig.canvas, (ax, twin1), vertOn = True, horizOn = False, color = 'red', linewidth = "3")

ax.legend(loc = "upper left")
twin1.legend(loc = "upper right")

plt.tight_layout()
```

With the above code I am getting a plot as below which is not as per my requirement:
[image]

Can anyone please suggest how to meet the above requirement?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your first step would be to sort your dataset by the x-axis variable. With plotly, you easily set multiple Y-axis: https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/

Comment: @amance - Thank you for the feedback. But the requirement is not only multiple Y-axis, but also the cursors and value tooltips as shown in the first image of my question. I am unable to get them in plotly!!